# send request to eve server blocking.but from python shell serves well

Tags: python, flask, eve

I have written some function shown below in server.py file.

```
import requests 
@app.route('/similarwords')
def test():
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/searchActivity'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print response
```

while running server, I make a request to "similarwords" endpoint. at requests.get(url) server was blocking.
And while send request to other urls example "www.google.com" serving correct.

And at python console it executing fine.

```
>> import requests
>> requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/searchActivity") 
>> Response[200]
```

what's the problem. I am executing my project in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned whether the "blocking" occurs only on local setup or even in production. I assume it is local-only.

Turns out

> the development server is single threaded, so when you call a url
>   served by that application from within the application itself, you
>   create a deadlock situation.

I too ran into this problem earlier and found about it [here](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/flask-cannot-fetch-a-url-on-localhost/).
The article also suggests workaround like using `gunicorn` locally to get past the "limitation" and warns that in a heroku-free tier type setup, the problem may come back.